# Зависимость textbox от combobox

Tags: c#

Необходимо реализовать программу
Которая рассчитывает например окружность, трапецию и параболу... необходимо в интерфейсе программы реализовать что бы в зависимости от того что выбрано в combobox рассчитывалось по разным формулам подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Приложите код, который у вас уже есть, чтобы вопрос не закрыли как "[домашнюю работу - делайте сами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Answer (score 1):

[image: работа примера]

Идея реализации довольно проста. На гл.окне размещаем `ComboBox` и `Panel`. Создаем коллекцию нужных фигур, в комбобоксе отображаем названия фигур. После того как сделан выбор той или иной фигуры, отображаем в панеле связанную с этой фигурой `UserContorl`. Вычисление площади происходит в классе фигуры.

Создадим класс абстрактн.фигуры

```
public abstract class Figure
{
    //ctor
    public Figure(string figureName, UserControl userControl)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(figureName)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(figureName));
        if (userControl == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userControl));

        Name = figureName;
        Control = userControl;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public UserControl Control { get; private set; }

    public double Area => GetArea();

    protected virtual double GetArea()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

А теперь класс Окружности

```
public class Circle : Figure
{

    public Circle(string figureName, UserControl userControl,
                  double diameter) : base(figureName, userControl)
    {
        if (diameter <= 0) throw new ArgumentException($"Неверное значение для {nameof(diameter)}");
        Diameter = diameter;

        //даем ссылку вьюшке
        (Control as CircleView).Circle = this;
    }

    private double _Diameter;
    public double Diameter
    {
        get => _Diameter;
        set
        {
            _Diameter = value;
            _Radius = _Diameter / 2;
        }
    }

    private double _Radius;
    public double Radius
    {
        get => _Radius;
        set
        {
            _Radius = value;
            _Diameter = _Radius * 2;
        }
    }

    protected override double GetArea()
    {
        return Math.PI * Math.Pow(Radius, 2);
    }
}
```

классы "пустой фигуры" и "трапеции" я показывать не буду, но их вы можете написать сами.
Вот кодбихайнд `UserControl` для окружности

```
public partial class CircleView : UserControl
{
    //источник привязок
    private BindingSource _bs = new BindingSource();

    public CircleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //тип данных
        _bs.DataSource = typeof(Circle);

        //привязка для текстбокса Радиуса
        var radiusBinding = new Binding("Text", _bs, nameof(Circle.Radius),
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        _textBoxRadius.DataBindings.Add(radiusBinding);

        //привязка для текстбокса Диаметра
        var diameterBinding = new Binding("Text", _bs, nameof(Circle.Diameter),
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        _textBoxDiameter.DataBindings.Add(diameterBinding);

        //привязка для вывода площади фигуры
        var labelBinding = new Binding("Text", _bs, nameof(Circle.Area),
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 0, "f4");
        _labelArea.DataBindings.Add(labelBinding);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Рабочая окружность
    /// </summary>
    public Circle Circle
    {
        get => _bs.Current as Circle;
        set
        {
            _bs.Clear();
            _bs.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

А вот кодбихайнд гл.окна (формы)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //источник данных (коллекции фигур)
    private Context _context = new Context();
    //источник привязок
    private BindingSource _bsFigures = new BindingSource();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();

        //загрузка данных
        LoadData();

        //настройка окна
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //устанавливаем тип источника данных
        _bsFigures.DataSource = typeof(List<Figure>);
        //подписываемся на изменение текущей выбранной фигуры
        _bsFigures.CurrentChanged += BsFigures_CurrentChanged;

        //делаем привязку для комбобокса
        _comboBoxFigures.DataSource = _bsFigures;
        //комбобокс будет отображать названия фигур из коллекции
        _comboBoxFigures.DisplayMember = nameof(Figure.Name);
    }

    private void BsFigures_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //подготовка панели
        _panelOutput.Controls.Clear();
        //отображение UserControl связанной с соотв.фигурой
        _panelOutput.Controls.Add((_bsFigures.Current as Figure).Control);
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        _bsFigures.DataSource = _context.GetFigures();
    }
}
```

Класс создающий коллекцию фигур такой

```
public class Context
{
    private List<Figure> _figures;

    //ctor
    public Context()
    {
        _figures = new List<Figure>
        {
            new EmptyFigure("Какая?", new EmptyFigureView()),
            new Circle("Окружность", new CircleView(), 1),
            new Trapezium("Трапеция", new TrapeziumView(), 1, 2, 1)
        };
    }

    public List<Figure> GetFigures()
    {
        return _figures;
    }
}
```